# How to Resize vector icons in settings PreferenceScreen Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a settings page and I am using vector icons and they auto resize to to fit the view I want to make them smaller how to do that , I can use *PNG* images for that but I want to do it with vector image how can this be done
here is my `settings.xml` code:

```
<PreferenceScreen 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/preferences_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_category_preferences">

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:divider="@null"
            android:key="settings_data"
            android:title="Backup And Encrypt"
            android:icon="@drawable/vec_new_backup"/>

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:divider="@null"
            android:key="settings_interface"
            android:title="Event Design"
        android:icon="@drawable/vec_note_design"/>

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:divider="@null"
            android:key="settings_navigation"
            android:title="@string/settings_screen_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/vec_navi"/>

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="settings_behaviors"
            android:title="@string/settings_screen_behaviors"
            android:icon="@drawable/vec_behaviour"/>

    <PreferenceScreen
            android:divider="@null"
            android:key="settings_notifications"
            android:title="@string/settings_screen_notifications"
            android:icon="@drawable/vec_noti"/>


</PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/preferences_category"
    android:title="@string/help">

    <Preference
            android:divider="@null"
            android:key="settings_tour_show_again"
            android:title="@string/settings_tour_show_again"
            android:icon="@drawable/vec_tour"
            android:summary="@string/settings_tour_show_again_summary"/>

</PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/preferences_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_category_about">

    <Preference
            android:divider="@null"
            android:title="@string/settings_statistics"
            android:icon="@drawable/vec_stat">
        <intent android:targetPackage="com.lalitesh.datenoteapp"
                android:targetClass="com.lalitesh.datenoteapp.StatsActivity"/>
    </Preference>

    <Preference
            android:divider="@null"
            android:title="@string/settings_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/vec_info">
        <intent android:targetPackage="com.lalitesh.datenoteapp"
                android:targetClass="com.lalitesh.datenoteapp.AboutActivity"/>
    </Preference>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

All these images used here is present in the *drawable* folder as `xml` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resize the svg xml  file.

Go to the svg xml drawable file and change width and height of the svg icon.

Comment: Yo welcome.Please upvote my answer if you find its helpful